# What does a Server do once it receives a request from a client?

Tags: http, response

I'm trying to get down to the details of what happens once a server gets a request from a client...

Open a socket on the port specified by the request...

Then access the asset or resource?

What if the resource refers to a cgi/script?

What "layers" does the request info have to pass through?

How is the response generated?

I've looked up info on "how the internet works", and "request response cycle", but I'm looking for details as to what happens inside the server.

Comment: You seem to be mixing a question about how socket communication works with how a web server works and I'm not sure which to answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand in detail what goes on in the server from a web developer standpoint... help me phrase my question better.

Comment: Which server? Which kind of request? Your question is too broad. Voting to close.

Comment: John there was a time when we didn't understand what we were trying to ask either. Be patient.

Comment: @Spencer: that doesn't mean the question should remain open. Besides, he's duplicating his own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102582/how-does-the-browser-server-work-together-to-display-an-html-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're having a little trouble separating out the different parts of your question so I'll do my best to help you out with that.

First and foremost, a common method for understanding communication between two computers is described using what is called the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). This model attempts to distinguish the responsibilities between each protocol in a protocol stack. For example, when you surf a website on your home network the protocol stack is most likely something like

```
Ethernet-IPv4-TCP-HTTP
```

This modularization of protocols is used to create a separation of concerns so that developers don't have to "reinvent the wheel" each time they try to get two computers to communicate in some way. If you're trying to write a chat program you don't want to worry about packet loss or internet routing methodologies so you go ahead and take advantage of the lower level protocols that already exist and handle more of the nitty gritty stuff for you.

When people refer to socket communication these days they're typically using TCP or UDP. These are both known as transport protocols. If you'd like to learn more of the fine details on socket communication I would start with UDP because it's a simpler protocol and then move on to TCP.

While your web server is aware of some information in the lower level protocols it doesn't really do much with it. Primarily that's all handled by the operating system libraries which eventually hand the web server some raw HTTP data which the web server then begins to process.

To add another layer, HTTP has nothing to do with the gateway language running behind the scenes. This is fairly obvious due to the fact that the protocol is the same whether the web server is serving CGI perl scripts, PHP, ASP.Net or static HTML files. HTTP simply makes the request and the webserver processes the request accordingly.

Hopefully this clarifies a few concepts for you and gives you a better idea what you're trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the server. An apache 2 server could do any amount of request rewriting, automatic responses (301, 303, 307, 403, 404, 500) based on rules, starting a CGI script, exchanging data with a FastCGI script, passing some data to a script module like `mod_php`, and so on. The CouchDB web server would do something else entirely.

Basically, aside from parsing the request and sending back the appropriate response, there's no real common aspect to web servers.

You could try looking into the documentation of the various web servers: Apache, IIS, lighttpd, nginx...

Comment: Yeah I see how that can get complicated. Is there a way to generally describe what happens inside the server across the server variations?

Answer (score 1):

[image: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/images/IIS_impflow.gif]